# Implicit this parameter in GDB

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, this, clion

I'm using Clion. How to see value of `this` parameter in gdb? It isn't in "Variables" section now. I've tried to print it using "Evaluate expression", but it didn't help me, it just printed `{void (my_class * const)} 0x7fff5fbff298`.

Also, can you explain why is it happening?

Answer (score 1):

Well, technically, `this` is just a pointer to the object that owns it, so it should always be a regular pointer address the points to certain class. It's nothing special.

Now, once you dereference the pointer, you will be referring to the actual object. So you should try referencing `*this` when you want to print out the actual object.

Comment: It prints `{void (my_class * const)} 0x7fff5fbff298 `.

Comment: Enter in gdb watches: `*(my_class*)this`. Also, this is strange as `*this` always worked for me.